# Probability of success in Fudge/ Fate dice rolls considering failures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

I'm creating a game system based on Fudge/Fate dice rolls and I need to validate if a have a fair distribution. Since I don't have much contact with this for a long time (since high school), I figure that someone here could help me with this.

For those that don't know, a Fudge/Fate dice is a common 6 sided die (d6) where you have 2 faces for each value (-1, 0, +1): (-1, -1, 0, 0, +1, +1).
In a Fudge/Fate die, -1 represents a failure and +1 represents a success and for each roll, a failure cancels a success (and 0 means neither).

Then, consider that we always sum the results.
For example, rolling 4 dices (dices are always rolled simultaneously):

- 4dF {0, 0, +1, -1} = 0
- 4dF {0, 0, +1, +1} = +2
- 4dF {0, 0, -1, -1} = -2

I'm trying to discover the probability of getting, for example, at least +20 in 100 rolls. I want to make a spreadsheet where I have the Y-axis as the number of rolls and X-axis as the desired number.

My goal with that is to establish the player range of success based on the number of rolls he has available.

Comment: For the "getting $20$ in $100$ rolls" question, does that mean at least $20$, or exactly $20$?

Comment: @quasi Yes, thanks for noticing that, I was reviewing the post and hit save by accident :)

It means 20 success or more (+20, +21, +30...).

Comment: Also, if the player's goal is, say $20$, and $100$ rolls are available, can the player stop on $20$ if the goal is achieved in less than $100$ rolls?

Comment: @quasi He will roll all dices at the same time. So the player will not have control over this to stop when he achieves the "goal". Meaning that in a 10dF I want 5 success or higher to be considered a "true success".

Comment: Got it -- simultaneous rolls. The notation 
10dF" means $10$ dice are rolled, but what does "F" mean?

Comment: @quasi "F" is just for "Fate" or "Fudge" - the special dice I've mentioned in the post :). I'm gonna update the post with those premises to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nonnegative integers $n$, and integers $x$, let $p(n,x)$ be the probability of getting a score of at least $x$ in $n$ rolls.

Then we have the recursion
$$
p(n,x)=
\begin{cases}
0&\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,n <  x\\[4pt]
1&\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,-n \ge x\\[4pt]
\frac{1}{3}p(n-1,x-1)+
+\frac{1}{3}p(n-1,x)+
+\frac{1}{3}p(n-1,x+1)
&\;\;\;\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Implementing the recursion in Maple, we get 
$$p(100,20)=\frac{a}{b}\approx .008336093451$$
where $a,b$ are given by
\begin{align*}
a&=159119821311220187192678211640711891517682398\\[4pt]
b&=19088056323407827075424486287615602692670648963
\end{align*}

**Note:**$\;$The above recursion yields an *exact* answer as a fraction, but as you can see, the numerators and denominators can be huge, so this method would require a programming language implementation, e.g., Python, or a CAS, such as Maple, rather than, say, Excel.

Here's an implementation in Maple . . .

[image]

Here is a table showing the approximate values of $p(100,x)$, for $1\le x \le 100$ . . .

[image]

Comment: Wow, this surely seems a very complete answer. But since my knowledge is very limited I have to admit I understood very little of it. Could you elaborate a bit in the methodology you are using to solve this? I barely know the notation, but I'm more concerned of getting the grasp of the approach. I have to make an observation: In my scenario a player will rarely have to roll more than 100 dices.

Comment: If $n < x$, you can't win, since even if all $n$ rolls come up with value $1$, your score (starting at 0) would be $n$, which is less than the needed value of $x$.

Comment: If $-n \ge x$, you can't lose, since even if all $n$ rolls come up with value $-1$, your score (starting at 0) would be $-n$, which is at least $x$ (so you win).

Comment: Finally, in all other cases, after rolling once, there are $n-1$ rolls remaining, and 3 possible results for the score after the roll, each with probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: So the basic idea is that the probability of winning is either immediately $0$ or $1$, in the cases where $n < x$, or $-n \ge x$, or else the probability is the sum of the weighted probabilities of the $3$ subcases, based on the results of the next roll (where in this case, the weights are all $\frac{1}{3}$).

Comment: Ok, so I've run the @saulspatz python code to print the roll/ target matrix and I reached the conclusion those probabilities may not be a good fit for my case (considering that those results are correct): https://repl.it/repls/LastWhitesmokeLinks

Comment: The odds seem extremely variable. For example, A player with 99 rolls has a higher probability of success trying to hit 84 (9.96839834) or more than 81 (2.77428913) or 82 (4.48713316).  
Also, the chances of getting 84 or more are "almost the same" as 93 (9.26903436).  
I was expecting something more linear, so that with 99 rolls, hitting from 1 to 99 would be proportionally more difficult.   
The ideia was that a player with more available rolls would have better chances (proportionally ) and with the target being higher, the difficulty would increase too.

Comment: Just to provide a context from a systemic view:
Imagine that **player1** has a value of 50 in one ability and **player2** has a value of 20. If both are challenged to hit 10 success or more, I'd expect the **player1** (more experienced) to have a higher chance - since he's more "trained". On the other hand, this advantage can't be that much to pose a treat or to eliminate all chances of failure.

Comment: With regard to the probabilities for hitting from 1 to 99, the probabilities will definitely decrease, getting very, very close to zero as the target value gets larger.

Comment: For example, the probability of getting a score of at least $99$ in $100$ rolls is
$$p(100,99)=\frac{a}{b}\approx 1.959728469657459{\,\times}10^{-46}$$
where $a,b$ are given by
$$a=101,\;\;\;b=515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001$$

Comment: Yes, but see that this does not seem to be the case. Look at the examples I gave before (the probabilities from getting at least 81, 82 or 84) - they are not decreasing as the number get higher. Actually, they are following another pattern. For instance: For **99 rolls**: (target: **79** = 9.1371769, target: **80** = 1.63077487, target: **92** = 1.39312517). For **34 rolls**: (target: **1** = 0.45833364, target: **18** = 8.40395879, target: **19** = 3.27615989). If you run the code in the link, you will see that the results seem a bit odd.

Comment: The probabilities _can't_ be more than $1$. For the floating point approximations, perhaps you're missing the powers of $10$ in the scientific notation? Note: The fractional results I gave are the _exact_ probabilities.

Comment: I just used the code @saulspatz provided, that matched your formula. Did you check the output of the code I shared to see if that's exactly what is supposed to be? Also, would you mind formatting your comment so it's easier to visualize? The notation seems broken.

Comment: I used my Maple code. If you get an answer out of the range $[0,1]$, that tells you it _can't_ be the correct probabilty. Possibly, you're getting underflow approximation errors. The Maple implementation doesn't have that issue.

Comment: Can you pastebin the mapple results here?

Comment: Sure, for what targets?

Comment: Thanks. Would be the same I outputed using the Python code: From 1 to 100 rolls with respective 1 to 100 target

Comment: I'll edit the results into my answer (in about 30 mins).

Comment: But first, let me ask you. Aren't you intending to _graph_ the results? If so, when the $p$-values get too low, there's no point graphing them, since they would appear as if they were zero.

Comment: Thanks... I'm gonna generate a spreadsheet to demonstrate the probabilities only from 1 to 100 rolls (columns ) and 1 to 100 target (rows). So I guess the only 0 values would be when the number of the target is superior of the rows (don't know if answered your question)

Comment: Ok, no problem, I'll post the results in a little while.

Comment: I edited in an image showing the approximate values of $p(100,x)$, for $1\le x \le 100$.

Answer (score 1):

You are really rolling a d3 with results of $-1,0,+1$.  For reasonable numbers of dice the normal approximation is a good one.  The mean of a single roll is $0$, so the mean of a number of rolls is as well.  The variance of a single roll is $\frac 23$ so the variance of $n$ rolls will be $\frac {2n}3$.  If we take those as the parameters of a normal distribution, the variance of $100$ rolls is about $66.67$ and the standard deviation is about $8.165$.  Getting $+20$ on $100$ rolls is then about $+2.45 \sigma$.  From a [cumulative z-score table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) the chance of doing this well or better is about $0.00714$ or a chance in $140$.  If you want to generate this in Excel the Wikipedia article gives it in terms of the error function, which Excel supplies.

Comment: Yes, the probability is the same as a d3, I was just giving the context as the dice has actually 6 sides. I'm sorry I can't contribute too much to the discussion since my knowledge is very limited.
   
Just wanna ask: Are you considering that when summing the results, a +1 roll will be canceled by a -1 too?

For example, let's say a player has 5 available rolls, and for him, to succeed he needs to roll at least +2, that means: {0,0,0,+1,+1} or {0, +1,-1,+1, +1} and so on.

Comment: Yes.  Considering the variance of the sum takes care of all combinations of $\pm 1$ with the same sum

Comment: It is the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which says the sum of independent random variables approaches the normal distribution when there are lots of them.  Once you know how many standard deviations you are away from the mean you can use the z-score in this approximation.   I am surprised the approximation is so bad comparing to quasi's exact result.

Comment: I like that your aproach seems very objective. Is there a formula for that? I'd like a little more direction on the solution since I'm very lay in the subject. I didn't understand, is the cumulative z-score a technique for those scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment on quasi's answer, but it won't fit in a comment.

Unless you are considering very large numbers of dice, you can do the calculations in floating point, without appreciable loss of accuracy.  Here's a python implementation:

```
cache = dict()
def p(n,x):
    if n < x: return 0
    if -n >= x: return 1
    if (n,x) in cache:
        return cache[n,x]
    cache[n,x]= (p(n-1,x-1)+p(n-1, x)+p(n-1,x+1))/3
    return cache[n,x]
print(p(100,20))

0.008336093451070253
```

The function evaluation is instantaneous, and as you see, the answer agrees with all $12$ decimal places given in quasi's answer.